# How to formally define the set of function that an guarantee a unique optima in constraint maximisation problem

Tags: constrained-optimization

We know that a strict concave function can guarantee a unique maximum. But in a constraint maximisation problem, there can still exists a unique maximum when the function is not concave. My question is **how to formally define the set of functions that can guarantee a unique optima in constraint maximisation problem?**

For example, the picture below would not be in this set as there are two disjoint local maximum.One optima is at the peak and the other is at the boundary.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying anything about the function or the constraint, there is no simple condition that is both necessary and sufficient for a unique maxima, except for the trivial condition of saying that it is the set of functions with a unique maxima.

If you really want to, you could define this formally (in a trivial and unhelpful way) by formally defining the set of functions with unique maximising points.  For example, consider the set of univariate real functions of the form $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathscr{F} \equiv \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ denote the function-space for these functions.  Given a constraint set $\mathcal{D} \in \mathbb{R}$, the set of functions with a unique maxima on this constraint set can be defined as:

$$\hat{\mathscr{F}} (\mathcal{D}) \equiv \{ f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} | (\exists x \in \mathcal{D}) (\forall x' \in \mathcal{D}-\{ x \}): f(x) > f(x') \}.$$